# NFS showing Security Contexts "?" / "blank" on Client?

Tags: linux, nfs, file-sharing

I'm using NFSv4 and used following `/etc/exports` on Server (lets say, `xx.xx.xx.x0`):

```
/var/www/html/project xx.xx.xx.x101(rw)
/var/www/html/project xx.xx.xx.x102(rw)
```

And each Client is showing something like below, when i check `mount`:

```
xx.xx.xx.x0:/var/www/html/project on /var/www/html/project type nfs (rw,vers=4,addr=xx.xx.xx.x0,clientaddr=xx.xx.xx.x101)
```

But when i check into the mounted directory `ls -laZ` (with **Z** option), it is showing like:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 11 user1   user1 ?   4.0K Mar  9 02:36 .
drwxr-xr-x. 26 user1   user1 ?   4.0K Mar  8 18:17 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  9 user1   user1 ?   4.0K Sep  3  2012 wp-admin
drwxrwxrwx.  8 user1   user1 ?   4.0K Dec 12 09:47 wp-content
drwxrwxrwx.  8 user1   user1 ?   4.0K Oct 16 12:04 wp-includes
-rwxrwxr--.  1 user1   user1 ?    647 Mar  8 18:54 .htaccess
-rwxrwxr--.  1 user1   user1 ?    395 Dec 12 09:49 index.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 user1   user1 ?    20K Dec 12 09:49 license.txt
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 user1   user1 ?   9.0K Dec 12 09:49 readme.html
```

The problems are the `?` Question Marks, which i believe is showing wrong File Security Context Values.

- Any good idea on it please?

*Note: SELinux is disabled, on every machines.*

Comment: Do you have SELinux enable NFS share?

Comment: It looks like the uid and gid of the files (as exported by the NFS server) do not exist on the client. Is there a group called `user1` on both server and the client ? And if so could you check your `/etc/group` to see if the `gid` differ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it by myself that i realized `SELinux` on Clients, was blocking the Security Context Permissions whilst NFS Server is totally disabling the SELinux. So i disable the `SELinux` on this Client machines and rebooted, then the exactly the same File/Directory Security Contexts are showing on all ends.